# Взаимодействие массивов во Vue JS

Tags: vue.js

Возникла проблема с Vue JS - в data объявлены 2 пустых массива. Вначале работы я заполняю массив A сотней вложенных массивов.
Позже, при действия пользователя (клик по отрисованному элементу), мне нужно взять из массива А элемент, соответствующий кликнутому блоку и "развернуть" для пользователя, чтобы он мог редактировать все его поля.
Для этого я беру пустой массив Б и присваиваю ему целевой элемент массива А.
А потом через v-for отрисовываю input-ы с v-model из содержимого массива Б.

Проблема в следующем - после того как я приравнял массив Б к элементу массива А, они становятся будто связаны и любое изменение элемента массива Б влечет идентичное изменение во вложенном массиве А.

Не могу найти решения, куда смотреть? Нужно чтобы массив Б был просто копией элемента массива А и жил своей жизнью.

Пример

```
var app = new Vue({
          el: '#app',
          data: {
            array_1:[['22','43','12'],['tg','gf','fc'],['ффф','иии','ппп']],
            array_2:[]
          },
          methods: {
          start_edit(arr){
            app.array_2=arr;
            }
          }

        });
```

при клике вызывается метод start_edit() c кликнутым элементом в качестве аргумента.
Предположим что это было так:

```
start_edit( array_1[2])
```

потом я меняю что-либо в array_2 и оно так же сразу меняется в array_1[2];

Как этого избежать?

Comment: В одном месте Вы пишите, что приравниваете один массив элементу другого.Т.е. читатель предполагает такую иснтрукцию в коде `this.a[i] = this.b, где b - это массив`. а в "приравниваю банально" совсем другая картина.

Comment: элемент, которому приравниваю тоже является массивом. Т.е. app.array_1[4] = ['1','2','3'...]

Comment: Дополнил вопрос коротким примером

Comment: Они не "будто связаны", а именно указывает на один и тот же объект. Вам следует сделать копию объекта (часто это ещё называют клонированием) и уже эту копию присвоить array_2. Операция присвоения `=` копию за Вас не сделает.

Comment: Аллилуйя, понял в чем проблема, спасибо!

Comment: Это свойственно фреймворку? Я давно работаю с js и jquery,  впервые с этим столкнулся...

Comment: Это везде так:)